# Xcopy command: How to display only the destination path of files copied

Tags: regex, xcopy

I am using the xcopy command like this -

```
xcopy  /y/i/e/f \oldLocation \newLocation
```

and i get output like this:

```
D:\temp\src\a.txt-> C:\Temp\a.txt
```

I need the xcopy to give me the complete path for just the destination files (only `C:\Temp\a.txt`) , after copy has succeeded. I have already tried /l flag too and it gives output like -

```
D:a.txt
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to manually extract the destination paths.

Comment: try switch /q/l. Though it will not fulfill your requirement but it will be close to it.

Comment: /q/l is displaying the number of files copied and no file names.
I want the output to show the destination path of files copied

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Powershell instead?

```
$oldLocation = "C:\OldFolder\" 
$newLocation = "D:\NewFolder\"

ForEach ($item in (gci $oldLocation)) {
    Write-Host $newLocation$item # Tells you what is being copied
    Copy-Item $item.fullname $newLocation$item
}
```